# New war file fails to reflect changes when deployed in jboss

Tags: linux, jboss

I made a web project, packaged it in a war file and deployed in jboss - worked great (I have done this 100 times before and succeeded). Today, I modify the same project and created the war file again and deployed the project to a clustered jboss server (jboss-4.0.5.GA running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)) as usual, I expect the changes to reflect.. When I accessed the project via the browser, my changes do not show. When I deploy the same war file on my laptop (Windows 7) the changes show perfectly! So I stop the jboss server, delete tmp and work directories on the clustered jboss servers plus the war file in farm folder... then deploy the new .war file.. I start the server again.. I expect the changes to show now on the server but they do not!! I have tried this over and over but no success in having the latest .war file run..

Has anyone experienced this and whats the solution?

Comment: Did you try to delete the work and tmp folder in the server instance?

Comment: yes i did delete the work and tmp folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was only fair to share the answer. The reason why changes did not reflect was because our ISP was caching javascript and css files. the painful solution was to rename my css files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance deploy to the 'default' configuration, while your cluster is running e.g. the 'all' one?